# call an object method passed as an argument to a function with or without using the call method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, call

```
var exe = {};
exe.print = 'Alphabet ';
exe.showLetter = function(val) {
    console.log(this.print+' is : '+val);
}

//var process = function(cb) { //case1
//var process = function(obj,str) { //case2
//var process = function(cb,obj) { //case3

var process = function(cb,str) { //case 4
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach(function(lett) {
        if(lett == 'C') {
            //cb(lett); //case1
            //obj[str].call(obj, lett); //case2
            //cb.call(obj, lett); //case3

            cb[str](lett); //case4


        }   
    })
}

//process(exe.showLetter); //undefined is : C , because 'this' points to window, case1
//process(exe, 'showLetter'); //Alphabet  is : C , case2
//process(exe.showLetter, exe); //Alphabet  is : C, case3

process(exe, 'showLetter'); //case4, without using call, Alphabet  is : C
```

From the example provided above, what are the advantages of using call? Or are `case2`, `case3`, and `case4` the same? As passing the object itself to the `process` function also shows the correct output!

Is it important to use `call` here or will it be wrong if `call` is not used?
(`case2` and `case3` being variants and `case1` will go wrong as `this` points to window as process is global function)

Please correct me, if I have understood things incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, case 2, 3 and 4 are basically all the same. `foo.bar()` is equivalent to `foo.bar.call(foo)` or `baz.call(foo)` where `baz = foo.bar`. The advantage of `.call` is that you can set the `this` value explicitly.

Comment: Interesting. So in a normal JS function call `obj.someFunc()`, the context of the function `someFunc()` (ie., `this`) is inferred by the leading `obj`. So if the function itself is called like in the `case 1` example above, `someFunc()`'s only context is `window`.